# Scroll to input fields but offset fixed nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you scroll down the page to

> Berechnen Sie hier Ihre Ersparnis mit SD-WAN

Below it you will see a form. Leave the form as is, do not fill anything in and click on the big red submit button that says the following on it:

> Kostenlos präzise Berechnung des Einsparungspotentials anfordern

You should see the browser scroll down to the first required input field but this is covered by the fixed nav.

I would like to fix this by adding some jquery to scroll to the input but also add an offset.

This is what I have tried so far, but the page is not scolling at all:

```
if ( $('.error').css('display') !== 'none' ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".roicalculatorblock .error").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Despite my code, the browser still scrolls down but the fixed nav covers the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the animation happening*, but looking at your code I would substract the header height and (after the `animate` is completed, remove the expanded header class to the body.

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".roicalculatorblock .error").eq(0).offset().top - $('#anchorNav').outerHeight()
}, 1000); // time
setTimeout(function() { $('body').addClass('nav-up').removeClass('nav-down') }, 1000) // wait for the time
```

*So it must be some other problem; perhaps share how you are biding the `submit` event  on the form (maybe you are just missing an `preventDefault()`).

Also take in consideration that value selection based on a class (which has multiple instances) is kind of risky.

Take a look on what your console logs about this code (not all `.error` element have same `display` value):

`$('.error').each(function() { console.log($(this).css('display')) } )`

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. What is the purpose of adding the nav-up class and removing the nav-down class at the end?

Comment: because otherwise the fixed (and expanded) nav will be "on top" of the first field with errors.